# PHP script not working inside Shopsite pro custom template

Tags: php

I am using php script in custom template but its not working. My custom template is inside ss-data/templates/products folder. I simply echo 'Hello'. but its not showing on productname.html page.

Please help, i m new to shopsite.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend to read carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And then reformulate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Web server is set to parse .html pages for php code. That is the likely issue.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I make changes to .htacess and parse .html page to php. And it worked.